# Why does Terra's extract(fun= mean) give different values than global(fun = mean) in R?

Tags: raster, r, extract, terra, mean

I am trying to extract mean and quartile ranges from a raster. I normally used terra's extract function to do this, but since I needed quartile numbers as well I tried it a different way. I noticed that I was getting slightly different means from these functions.

Here is some dummy data that gives similar results as when I do it on my real data.

For this example I used the shapefile of California and its counties from the California data portal. Found here: https://data.ca.gov/dataset/ca-geographic-boundaries/resource/b0007416-a325-4777-9295-368ea6b710e6

Here is what I did to use the extract function to get the mean from my raster:

```
#read in shapefile
cali_shp <- sf::st_read("CA_Counties_TIGER2016.shp")
#transform it
cali_area <-  st_transform(x= cali_shp , 5070)

#create my dummy raster that's the same extent as my shapefile
fake_cali_raster <- rast(ext(cali_area), ncols = 200, nrows = 500)

# give the raster the same projection
crs(fake_cali_raster) <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"

#give the dummy raster fake values
values(fake_cali_raster) <- runif(ncell(fake_cali_raster)) * 300


#here is where I use the extract function to get the mean
cali_extract <- terra::extract(fake_cali_raster , cali_area , fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE,  cali_df =TRUE)
print(cali_extract)

# #get county names for masked polygon
cali_extract$county <- cali_area$NAME

cali_df<- data.frame(cali_extract)

head(cali_df)
```

I need to get the 25th and 75th percentile as the same time as the mean so then I tried getting the mean this way using the global function. We will call this the global mean method.

```
counties_list <- unlist(cali_area$NAME)

ave_values <- list()
county_name <- list()
lower_quantile <- list()
upper_quantile <- list()

#mask the raster by each county
for (i in counties_list){
  print(i)
  county <- i
  masked_raster <- mask(fake_cali_raster, cali_area[cali_area$NAME == county,])
  cropped_raster <- crop(masked_raster, cali_area[cali_area$NAME == county,])
  plot(cropped_raster)
  cropped_raster
  raster_mean <- as.numeric(global(cropped_raster, "mean", na.rm = TRUE))
  print(raster_mean)
  quantiles  <- quantile(values(cropped_raster), probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE)
  #appen to lists
  ave_values <-c(ave_values, raster_mean)
  county_name <- c(county_name, county)
  lower_quantile <-c(lower_quantile, quantiles[1])
  upper_quantile <- c(upper_quantile, quantiles[2])
}

iqr_ave_df<- data.frame(
  county = unlist(county_name),
  mean = unlist(ave_values),
 quantile_low = unlist(lower_quantile),
 quantile_high = unlist(upper_quantile)
)
```

Here are some results showing the difference between the extract() mean method and the global() mean method. Which is more accurate?
[image]